# foreach gridview row, commandfield edit enable true or false

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, commandfield

here my code, but all in edit column enabled false, i want false editbutton depend on statuse value

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    statuse = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[6].ToString();
    if (statuse != null || statuse != "")
    {
        if (control is LinkButton)
        {
            LinkButton btn = control as LinkButton;
            btn.Enabled = btn.CommandName.Equals("Edit");
            btn.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? `btn.Enabled = statuse == null || statuse == ""`

Comment: I would use the RowDataBound event for this.

Comment: yes i was use rowdatabound. im looking for : if statuse value = "" then commandfieled enabled false. but after i try, all the command edit become false where statuse had or hadnt value

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's usually done in the RowDataBound event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the dataitem back to a row
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //find the edit button in the row with findcontrol
        LinkButton btn = e.Row.FindControl("EditButtonID") as LinkButton;

        //check the status of the correct data field and set the button properties
        if (row["statuse"].ToString() == "Closed")
        {
            btn.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            btn.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE

If the edit button is generated automatically, you have to find the LinkButton based on Column index.

```
LinkButton btn = e.Row.Cells[i].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
```

Comment: Updated my answer. If the edit button is in the first column, `i` will be `0`

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: update my answer :  LinkButton cmdField =e.Row.Cells[9].Controls[0] as LinkButton; 
 cmdField.Visible = false; --> error in here

Comment: Then there is no control in that column. Note that the index is zero based. Maybe post your gridview layout

Answer (score 0):

//here my aspx gridview

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "No" ItemStyle-Width="50"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblRowNumberA" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="ProposedBy" HeaderText="Proposer"  ReadOnly="true"
            ItemStyle-Width="10%" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" dataformatstring="{0:d}"
           ItemStyle-Width="100px" ReadOnly="True" />


        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Note" ItemStyle-Width="70%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
           <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label1ert" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Note") %>'></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <EditItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1edit" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%#Bind("Note") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
           </EditItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>


         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Compere to standard(s)" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
           <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label1sdf" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Justify") %>'></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Recommendation" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
           <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label1sdfqq" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <EditItemTemplate>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="DDStatus" runat="server">


<asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
           </EditItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:BoundField DataField="HRStatus" HeaderText="Status"  ReadOnly="true"
            ItemStyle-Width="250px" />

     <asp:CommandField  ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />

    </Columns>
```